# Visual studio 2019 debug variable

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I have problem with showing values of variables in debug mode. Using asp net core 3.1.
When in debug mode hovering over variables shows name and some value (example list shows item count) but when I click to expand nothing happens. Like shown

Hovering over the values:

[image: hover over values]

In local variable window is only "..."
[image: local variable window]

My current version 16.11.12

Answer (score 0):

Solved by

- uninstalling with [InstallCleanup.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/uninstall-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#remove-all-with-installcleanupexe)
- manually deleting visual studio files located at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio"